# How to create two subclasses of the model class in sequelize-typescript?

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I'm creating a node.js server with sequelize using sequelize-typescript. I have one entity - name it `Employee`.

In database all profiles stores in the same table but have two different types - say `Manager` and `Operator`.
Each type has its own relations with different tables - say:

```
Manager -> ManagerOptions

Operator -> OperatorOptions
```

I've created a model `Employee` and two subclasses - `Manager` and `Operator`. Each extending Employee, so have same base properties, and also have some additional properties in each subclass, such as `ManagerOprtions` and `OperatorOptions`.

```
// Employee.ts

import { Table, Column, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({
    tableName: 'employees'
})
export class Employee extends Model<Employee> {
    @Column public type_id: number;
    @Column public name: string;
    @Column public url: string;
}

// Manager.ts

import { Column, HasOne } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Employee } from './Employee';
import { ManagerInfo } from './ManagerInfo';

export class Manager extends Employee {
    @Column public subordinate_count: number;
    @HasOne(() => ManagerInfo, {
        foreignKey: 'manager_id',
        as: 'info'
    })
    public info: ManagerInfo;
}

// Operator.ts

import { Column, HasOne } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Employee } from './Employee';
import { OperatorInfo } from './OperatorInfo';

export class Operator extends Employee {
    @Column public calls_count: number;
    @HasOne(() => OperatorInfo, {
        foreignKey: 'operator_id',
        as: 'info'
    })
    public info: OperatorInfo;
}
```

How do I create such relations using `sequelize-typescript` (or just `sequelize`, if you're not familiar with this lib), so I can search `Employees` by `name` and have different models in the result set?

```
Search: "Mar"

Results:
+---------------------------------------+
| 1   Mark   Operator   OperatorOptions |
| 2   Mary   Manager    ManagerOptions  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Hope I've explained it right.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? i'm looking to do the same.

Comment: @rkstar no :( I ended up using 2 separate models for 1 table, copy-pasting some of their common properties into both models.

Comment: Is there any new solution for this? I'm trying to do similar thing @rkstar